# CakePHP Model Binding with TreeBehavior methods

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am making use of CakePHP TreeBehavior class.

```
$this->set('sports', $this->Sport->children(1,true));
```

As you can see bellow, the function returns the children I need, but it does not bind the models. The name of the sport is stored in a table Tags. The associations are defined properly in the model and it binds them if I use say the 'find' method for queries. But is there a way to use TreeBehavior functions and force model binding ?

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Sport' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'parent_id' => '1',
        'lft' => '6',
        'rght' => '7',
        'tag_id' => '51f0099f-ead0-4f41-8d0f-176c9c2b3e89'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Sport' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'parent_id' => '1',
        'lft' => '8',
        'rght' => '11',
        'tag_id' => '79177f20-f46a-11e2-96ba-00116b93c9e5'
    )
)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only direct children why not to use a Model::find method?

```
$this->Sport->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Sport.parent_id'=>1))
```